# CMDIFrameWndEx::UpdateWindow() crash

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an 64 bits MFC application in C++ with Visual Studio 2017, with the main frame, CMyMainFrm, inheriting from CMDIFrameWndEx.

When running, this function is executed:

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...

    CMyMainFrm* pMainFrame = new CMyMainFrm;

    (!pMainFrame || !pMainFrame->LoadFrame(nMainID))
    {
        delete pMainFrame;
        return FALSE;
    }

    m_pMainWnd = pMainFrame;

    // call DragAcceptFiles only if there's a suffix
    //  In an MDI app, this should occur immediately after setting m_pMainWnd
    // Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
    CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
    ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

    // Dispatch commands specified on the command line.  Will return FALSE if
    // app was launched with /RegServer, /Register, /Unregserver or /Unregister.
    // don't show initial view on startup
    cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand = CCommandLineInfo::FileNothing;
    if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
        return FALSE;

    // The main window has been initialized, so show and update it
    pMainFrame->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);
    pMainFrame->UpdateWindow(); // <--- CRASH!!!

    ...
}
```

m_nCmdShow is SW_SHOWNORMAL. LoadFrame() and ProcessShellCommand() seem to be working correctly. ShowWindow() gets to show the main window rectangle and a few controls.

The application runs fine normally but it crashes if the Windows size of text is different from 100% (in Settings, Display window).
[Change size of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIdxG.png)

Is this an MFC bug? Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: A [failed debug assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/assertion-failed-dialog-box) is not a crash. The dialog provides instructions on what to do.

Comment: It's not a debug assertion as it also happens in release.

Comment: `CWnd::UpdateWindow` **cannot** crash. It's implementation has an `ASSERT` statement, followed by a call to [UpdateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow). If you think this is incorrect, provide additional information, including the *specific* error mode as well as the complete callstack at the point of failure.

Comment: The bug is obviously elsewhere than in the code provided.  It's further in the implementation of pMainFrame->ShowWindow(), most likely in CMyMainFrm::OnCreate() or CMyMainFrm::OnInitialUpdate() (if it's a dialog), CMyMainFrm::OnEraseBkgnd(), CMyMainFrm::OnPaint(), or in one of its controls OnPaint(), or in related OnEraseBkgnd().